# getting value from arraylist (total cost of all three cars by calling computeCars ())

Tags: java

trying to get a value from with in an ArrayList. Here is a sample of my code

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    Car toyota= new Car("Toyota", "$10000", "300"+ "2003");
    Car nissan= new Car("Nissan", "$22000", "300"+ "2011");
    Car ford= new Car("Ford", "$15000", "350"+ "2010");

    ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    cars.add(toyota);        
    cars.add(nissan);
    cars.add(ford);
}

public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){

   // in heare i need a way of getting the total cost of all three cars by calling 
    //  computeCars ()
    System.out.println(cars.get());
}
```

i have another method that is calculating the total cost including the tax.

```
class Car {
    public Car (String name, int price, int, tax, int year){
        constructor.......
    }

    public void computeCars (){
        int  totalprice= price+tax;
        System.out.println (name + "\t" +totalprice+"\t"+year );
     } 
}
```

in the main class

```
public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){
        cars.get(i).computeCars ();
        totalAmount=+ ?? // in need to add the computed values of totalprice from the  Car class?
    }
}
```

Comment: How about returning the price from `computeCars()`?

Comment: Your `Car` constructor and how you call it... that does not go together. The signature is `String, int, int, int`, but you pass in 3 `String`s - that probably doesn't even compile, now does it?

Comment: compute cars should return a value. @domdom that is not the only mistake we can see there

Comment: @XtremeBaumer no, absolutely not. But that seems like the most obvious and severe one... OP has a long way to go with getting this to work.

Comment: By the way, who upvotes and favorites questions like these? Fellow student of the same course who's working with you on the assignment?

Comment: @domdom I sometime favorites those questions to find them easier later in the hope they get edited.

Comment: and what I gave the first right answer and nothing... now I understand why such noob questions deserve downvote and no answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just make the `computeCars()` method return the value, and then move the first instruction of the `for` loop as the value you use to increment your total

```
class Car {
    public Car (String name, int price, int, tax, int year){
        constructor.......
    }

    public int computeCars(){
        return totalprice= price+tax;
    }

    public void printComputeCars(){
        System.out.println (name + "\t" + computeCars() +"\t" + year );
    }
}

public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){
        totalAmount=+ cars.get(i).computeCars();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change type of `computeCars()` to `int` which returns `totalprice` while calling the method.

```
class Car {
    public Car (String name, int price, int, tax, int year){
        constructor.......
    }

    public int computeCars (){
        int  totalprice= price+tax;
        System.out.println (name + "\t" +totalprice+"\t"+year );
        return totalprice;
     } 
}
```

Then in `for` loop, Add `totalprice` to `totalamount` for each `car`.

```
public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){

        totalAmount+= cars.get(i).computeCars(); // compute totalprice for each car
    }

    System.out.println(totalAmount);
}
```

**EDIT :**

First change you can make is separating the logic for `computing total price` and `printing the details` And you should also write the method names properly.

```
public void printDetails()
{
    int totalprice = computePrice();
    StringBuffer details=new StringBuffer(name).append(" \t$").append(totalprice).append(" \t").append(year);
    System.out.println (details);
}

public int computePrice()
{
    int totalprice = price+tax;
    return totalprice;
}
```

After making all changes, You may end up with lots of `Compilation Errors` as your `constructor` call from main method doesn't match with the `defined constructor`.

So you need to make changes in the `calls` of the constructor.

```
Car toyota= new Car("Toyota", 10000, 300, 2003);
Car nissan= new Car("Nissan", 22000, 300, 2011);
Car ford= new Car("Ford", 15000, 350, 2010);
```

Comment: This is true for all other answers as well, but yours is currently the highest voted so I'll note it here: I wish someone would also point to the other issues in OPs code, including the bad design - `computeCars()`, for example, is a horribly misleading name for what that method does. And the constructor and how OP calls it?

Comment: @domdom Any more changes do you require me to make?

Comment: Sanket, of course you can do as you please. Personally, I would point out the issues with how OP is trying to call the `Car` constructor (`String` vs `int`, including the `$`, using String concatenation, ...).

Answer (score 0):

```
cars.stream().mapToInt(i -> i.computeCars()).sum();
```

and you must change your method computeCars like that:

```
public int computeCars (){
        int  totalprice= price+tax;
        System.out.println (name + "\t" +totalprice+"\t"+year );
        return totalprice;
     }
```

You have mistake here too:

```
 Car toyota= new Car("Toyota", "$10000", "300"+ "2003");
```

You should change the style of creating your car objects:

```
 Car toyota= new Car("Toyota", 10000, 300, 2003);
```

Comment: Maybe mention that this is Java 8+ only (or am I mistaken?). Also, there is so much more wrong with OP's code.

Comment: yep yep there is, but in short thats a solution :)

Comment: the other is a compilation error that I think he/she will solve anyway

Answer (score 0):

Add a method in the Car class to compute the total price:

```
public int getTotalPrice() {
    return price + tax;
}

public void computeCars (){
    System.out.println (name + "\t" +getTotalPrice()+"\t"+year );
}
```

Then your processCars method becomes:

```
public static void processCar(ArrayList<Car> cars){
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){
        totalAmount=+ cars.get(i).getTotalPrice();
    }
    System.out.println("Total: " + totalAmount);
}
```